# Akka cluster node rejoin after removed

Tags: scala, akka, akka-cluster

I am trying to understand how akka cluster membership work and how to use it in the following scenario.

I have N nodes, I wish to use sharding and singletons. But these nodes are controlled from the outside, I want to (automatically or manually, doesn't matter) scale up and scale down them. To add new nodes and to shutdown existing (and later drop) is easy.

But is it possible to temporary remove one node from the cluster and return it back? When I am trying to do so, the downing mechanism simply terminates the actor system and the JVM (gracefully). I want to have ability to keep actor system up, but have this node in "passive" state, not accepting to serve singletons or shards (or anything else), but waiting to be manually added (with restart if necessary). For example, listening some sort of message queue and to be rejoined when asked to do so.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible for an actor system to rejoin a cluster after it has exited the cluster (or been declared down by enough other nodes in the cluster to be removed).

[The docs are clear on this](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/cluster-membership.html)

> The actor system on a node that exited or was downed cannot join the cluster again. In particular, a node that was downed while being unreachable and then regains connectivity cannot rejoin the cluster. Instead, the process has to be restarted on the node, creating a new actor system that can go through the joining process again.

It may be possible (read: I'm not aware of anything that would prevent this), especially in the case where the node initiates its own removal from the cluster (possibly in response to a command sent through a non-cluster sidechannel, e.g. a local HTTP endpoint or through a message queue), for a node to leave the cluster and continue to run its local actor system as before.  When it's told to "rejoin", the node would terminate the actor system (but not the JVM), and then start up a new actor system and the new actor system would join the cluster.

That said, the only general benefit I can see for doing this sort of thing (vs. the much more orderly leave cluster then stop actor system and JVM and then restart the JVM) would be to eliminate the cold-start and JIT warmup time for the JVM, and I'd really wonder whether the extra complexity was worth it.  Cold-start and warm-up lag on scale-up can be pretty easily ameliorated by overprovisioning and being proactive about autoscaling, after all.